# Visual Studio text editor does not recognize F# source?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, f#, intellisense, text-editor

I have got the following problem with F# code recently: almost the complete code is underlines with curly red lines (indicating problems) and whenever I hover with the mouse cursor over any word the pop-up appears with the message "Unexpected token". IntelliSence doesn't work either.

[image: F# problem]

Nonetheless if I start the project it is executed without any problem.

This happens both to already existing F# files and to newly created F# projects. I remember it was working just 2-3 months ago!

I tried to deactivate all possible extensions but it doesn't help.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is F# your default language in Visual Studio? Is F# Interactive window floating around?

Comment: What do you mean by "default language"? Default layout was set to C# because it is the language I use most often. The F# Interactive wasn't here, but appeared immediately after opening it via View -> Other Windows -> F# Interactive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get this too.  Sometimes, simply exiting and going back into VS helps.  When I tweeted the problem, Don answered with this:

"do you have "python tools for visual studio alpha" installed? if so, uninstall it or apply the hot fix"

This wasn't relevant to me (as I haven't been anywhere near python) but I'm posting here in case it helps you.

-- Edit: here's a link to the patch, thanks to Alexander Galkin: http://pytools.codeplex.com/workitem/599

Comment: Great, this seems to be the reason, I have installed IronPython recently. Can you provide me with the link to the hotfix?

Comment: Sorry, that's all Don's tweet said and as it wasn't relevant to me I didn't follow it up.  Time to google!

Comment: Yes, I Google knew the [answer](http://pytools.codeplex.com/workitem/599). Thank you a lot for suggesting the right direction: I just removed the Python tools from VS2010 and it worked immediately, I didn't test the patch on my own. Could you please add the link to the patch into your post, so that the answer is complete?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen this situation before but here's a guess at why it's happening and how you might cure it.

Visual studio works on a system for plugins. Even the stuff that is "native", like the C#/F#/VB.NET project systems, are just plugins that uses the visual studio shell. It looks like the F# plugin has been damaged in someway.

If this is Visual Studio 2010:

- You might try opening the visual studio installer and trying a repair installation or deactivation and reactivating the F# project system

If this is Visual Studio 2008:

- You might try uninstalling and reinstalling the F# plugin

Comment: It is VS2010. I will try to find the medium I used for installation and retry it. I suggest that the problem appeared due to installation of some Iron languages.